# Lvalue required error with macro

Tags: c, macros

Why does the following code report an Lvalue required error?? And how can we write a macro that receives an array and the number of elements in the array as arguments and then print out the elements of the array??

```
#define arr(b) printf("%d",b++);\
               printf("%d",b);


int main()
{
    arr(5);
}
```

Comment: Ignoring that it doesn't "work" ... parenthesize everything inside the macro definition! Suppose it's "called" with `arr(6*3)` ... `#define arr(b) printf("%d", (b)++); printf("%d", b);`

Comment: Alright.. got it.. Can someone please answer the other part of the question??

Answer (score 4):

If you expand the macro, you get the following:

```
int main()
{
    printf("%d",5++);
    printf("%d",5);
}
```

You cannot postincrement the constant `5`, so you get an error.

Remember, macros aren't functions. If you want it to act like a function, simply make a function:

```
void arr(int b) {
    printf("%d",b++);
    printf("%d",b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because part of that macro expands to `5++`, which is not valid C.  Consider using `b+1` instead of `b++`.

Answer (score 1):

The first **l** in **lvalue** stands for left.

Only left values can be assigned.

when you write `x ++` you mean `x = x + 1` (also you get a value from it).

So the problem is it does not make sense to write `5 = 5 + 1`

maybe you would like to do this:

```
int x = 5;
arr(x);
```